# .htaccess cookie SameSite attribute modify

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with modifying cookie attributes in .htaccess file. I tryed these codes:

`Header always edit "Set-Cookie" ""`

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict`

`Header always Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict`

`Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict`

`Header always set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict`

but none of these have changed anything in cookie attributes. I can't get apache version, and apache has mod_headers.c.